# Need to assert error validation message when I give wrong User Name and submit it in Anuglar JS app

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I need to bind the  error message and test it. My code is below

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
            <strong class="text-danger ng-binding" title="Invalid Username">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Invalid Username</strong> 
<strong class="text-success ng-binding" title=""></strong>
         </div>
```

Test code is Here.

```
    var bindingResult = element(by.binding('what should i write here'));
it('Invalid name validation', function(){
LoginPage.setUserName('sdfdfds@test.com');
LoginPage.setPassWord('password');
expect(bindingResult.getText()).toEqual('Invalid user');
});
```

I need to validate the error message after submitting with wrong userName.[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `by.binding` you have to know the scope variable name being used in that html element.
For this you need to look at the actual source code.

Could be somethng like:

```
<strong class="text-danger ng-binding" title="{{theMessage}}">
```

and in protractor:

```
var bindingResult = element(by.binding('theMessage'));
```

alternatively use an xpath or css locator instead of loacting by binding